# Enable Nvidia GPU CUDA support for theano and PyMC3 for Windows 11

Tags: python, gpu, theano, pymc3

Has anyone figured out how to install GPU support for Theano and PyMC3 on Windows 11?  I keep getting an error message about a DLL load failure.  Here are the steps I’ve taken:

1. Install MSVC C++ Build tools and add to system variable path
2. Install latest Nvidia drivers, CUDA toolkit, and added cuDNN .dll files to folders
3. Created .theanorc with the following line `[global], device = cuda, floatX = float32` and added to base directory
4. Added 'THEANO_FLAGS' system variable with `floatX=float32,device=cuda` (is this redundant with step 3?)
5. Created the following conda environment:

`conda create -n pymc_env_gpu -c conda-forge python libpython mkl-service numba python-graphviz scipy arviz pandas scikit-learn m2w64-toolchain pygpu ipykernel statsmodels`

6. Activate new env and install pymc3 with `pip install pymc3`

The error message:  `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing m169e842c8a94977b534b5d54311bcacefb2595c2a7bb1124600448dca20d9048: The specified module could not be found.`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Should we guess what DLL is missing?

Comment: The error message is now included in the original post

Comment: That is a pretty improbable looking DLL name. I would guess something is seriously hosed in your setup. Try using a DLL dependency analysis tool to work out what is going on.